# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

so here is the error

```
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [error] [client 66.249.66.205] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3120): [client 66.249.66.205] r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /home/mysitecom/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php
[Mon Sep 30 00:09:53 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 66.249.66.205] redirected from r->uri = /images/2013/02/600x376_0.076827001313237200_pixnaz_ir_1.jpg
```

how can i find what is cuzing this ?

it seems a loop around index.php , with the exception of last one which is an image , most likely linked within one of my page (not index)

i'm using codeigniter which is a mvc framework and everything goes trough index.php file .... so it's a bit harder to understand where it goes wrong .

apparently it has something to do with htaccess (it's been mentioned in couple of blogs )

here is my htacc ... basically it removes index.php from all the links , nothing unusual

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule> 
AddType image/x-windows-bmp bmp
```

**i have a dedicated server**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an exception so that you are not rewriting `index.php` to `index.php?/index.php`. (Also, are you sure that you want a `/` after the `?`?)

Here's a RewriteCond to stop that loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != /index.php/
```

It should be inserted before the RewriteRule.

Comment: thanx , im going to try it .. and actually the `?` was extra , i've removed it .. but it wasn't really important

Comment: but  still , i have to ask why this is happening ... the sulotion might work but it shouldn't be like that in the first place

Comment: is it possible your index.php is a symlink? if so add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` to the conditions as well

Comment: i get `500 Internal Server Error` after adding new condition , my links are like this .. `www.site.com/index.php/users/get` and with current htacc my link are like  `www.site.com/users/get`

Comment: Look at your server logs. They are very likely to give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the loop is that apache creates an internal subrequest each time a rewrite is triggered in a .htaccess file. This is one of many reasons why rewrites in .htaccess should be avoided.
So if you do have access to your httpd.conf put the rewrites there.
If you can't put your rewrites in the config, if you really must use a .htaccess file then make sure to add a condition that breaks the loop.